# No permission to create new ember-cli app

Tags: macos, shell, ember.js, npm

Everytime I use the command `ember new myapp` it throws me these errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/MyAccount/.config/configstore/ember-cli.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:431:33)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at clientId (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js:22:21)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js:64:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember:26:3
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:14
    at process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
```

I tried to clean `npm` cache, but the problem remains. How to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the permissions

```
chmod -R 777 /Users/MyAccount/.config/configstore
```

or (if necessary)

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/MyAccount/.config/configstore
```

If you are concerned about security you can later change permissions, eg. block a guest

```
chmod -R 771 /Users/MyAccount/.config/configstore
```

each number sets the permissions of user, group, and other respectively. The numbers mean ([sourced from here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/chmod-codes-list-142654/)):

```
0 == --- == no access
1 == --x == execute
2 == -w- == write
3 == -wx == write / execute
4 == r-- == read
5 == r-x == read / execute
6 == rw- == read / write
7 == rwx == read / write / execute
```

Comment: why the number `777`?

Comment: I used -R to do this to the folder and all the contents. To  just change the permissions I the file do `chmod 777 /Users/MyAccount/.config/configstore/ember-cli.json`

Comment: I used the `771` in the `configstore` folder, just to avoid this problem in the future, while maintaining some concern with security. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i try to use the commands like ng serve/ng version.I tried this command and it worked

chmod -R 777 /Users/MyAccount/.config/configstore

Replace myAccount with your account name.It should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also run ng serve/ng version with sudo permissions.

```
sudo ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   '/home/ethem/.config/configstore/ember-cli.json'

You have to give permission like user:group. Your user enough for your group also. sudo chown -R OS_USER:OS_USER .config

For example for above error this command fixed

```
sudo chown -R ethem:ethem .config
```

Answer (score 0):

:) Get the same error and fixed it with below command
`sudo chmod 777 /Users/{{-username-}}/.babel.json`
or open new terminal hit below commnd
`ls -al`
check that file
if you got then hit
`sudo chmod 777 .babel.json`